# C++ Thread error?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

So I have an issue with this program that I tried to make just to mess around with. I have never had this problem before. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
void update(){
system("cls");
std::cout << "Wow dud";
system("pause >nul");
}

int main(){
std::thread wow(update);
while(true){
wow.join();
wow.detach();
    }
}
```

and the error is: [well, error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuTTy.png)

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What is the desired behavior of the program?

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow.com must have all pertinent information included in the question itself, as plain text. Links to external sites, that can stop working at any time rendering the question meaningless, are unacceptable.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I don't believe you can call functions on a thread once `detach` has been called. It's safe to call `join` multiple times, but once detached you can't do anything with the `thread`.

Comment: The purpose is to keep on clearing the screen, put out "wow dud" and then pause. I was messing around and I randomly had this hour

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not clear what the error is but the lifecycle is obviously wrong. Thread is created once before the loop but then in the loop it's repeatedly joined and detached. Therefore any subsequent iteration of the loop performs invalid operation on already dead thread. Maybe you meant:

```
  while(true){
      std::thread wow(update);
      wow.join();
      wow.detach();
  }
```